# Include submodules into source packages of releases

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

We have a repository which also has some small dependencies collected as submodules.
To make it easier for users, I would like the source archives of releases to contain the sources of the submodules as well.
If I create a release using gitlab, however, the submodules are only included as empty folders.

Is there a way to have the submodules included?
Alternatively, is there a way that I can place my own source archives as part of the release and not have the ones generated by gitlab automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a CI job that pulls submodules and packages them into a tarball. Then you can set that as an artifact, which can be downloaded from a URI in this form:

```
https://gitlab.com/<user>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<branch|tag>/raw/<path to your tarbal>.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did using git-archive-all. Now I have the problem that I have my complete tarball and the 4 incomplete source code archives generated by gitlab. Do you know how I can remove the latter to avoid confusion?

Comment: Not really, for my project I have a script that adds a table in the release notes, which makes the default download not as prominent

Example result: https://gitlab.com/mattbas/glaxnimate/-/releases#glaxnimate-015
Script: https://gitlab.com/mattbas/glaxnimate/-/blob/master/deploy/make_release.py

Comment: Cool idea. I will need to think about how this could be applied for our project. Thanks.